# accessing many grib messages at once with pygrib

Tags: python, grib

I need to access some grib files. I have figured out how to do it, using pygrib. 
However, the only way I figured out how to do it is painstakingly slow.

I have 34 years of 3hrly data, they are organized in ~36 files per year (one every 10 days more or less). for a total of about 1000 files.

Each file has ~80 “messages” (8 values per day for 10 days). (they are spatial data, so they have (x,y) dimensions).

To read all my data I write:

```
grbfile = pygrib.index(filename, 'shortName', 'typeOfLevel', 'level') 
var1 = grbfile.select(typeOfLevel='pressureFromGroundLayer', level=180, shortName='unknown')
for it in np.arange(len(var1)):
    var_values, lat1, lon1 = var1[it].data()
    if (it==0):
        tot_var = np.expand_dims(var_values,axis=0)
    else:
        tot_var = np.append(tot_var, np.expand_dims(var_values,axis=0),axis=0)
```

and repeat this for each of the 1000 files.

is there a quicker way? like loading all the ~80 layers per grib files at once? something like:

```
var_values, lat1, lon1 = var1[:].data()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the data from all 80 messages in each file stacked up in one array.

I have to warn you, that that array will get very large, and may cause NumPy to throw a `MemoryError` (happened to me before) depending on your grid size etc.

That being said, you can do something like this:

```
# substitute with a list of your file names
# glob is a builtin  library that can help accomplish this
files = list_of_files

grib = pygrib.open(files[0]) # start with the first one

# grib message numbering starts at 1
data, lats, lons = grib.message(1).data()

# while np.expand_dims works, the following is shorter
# syntax wise and will accomplish the same thing
data = data[None,...] # add an empty dimension as axis 0

for m in xrange(2, grib.messages + 1):
    data = np.vstack((data, grib.message(m).values[None,...]))

grib.close()  # good practice

# now data has all the values from each message in the first file stacked up 
# time to stack the rest on there
for file_ in files[1:]:  # all except the first file which we've done
    grib = pygrib.open(file_)
    for msg in grib:
       data = np.vstack((data, msg.values[None,...]))

   grib.close()
print data.shape # should be (80 * len(files), nlats, nlons)
```

This may gain you some speed. `pygrib.open` objects act like generators, so they pass you each `pygrib.gribmessage` object as it's called for instead of building a list of them like the `select()` method of a `pygrib.index` does. If you need all the messages in a particular file then this is the way I would access them.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not dead set on pygrib, you can now do this fairly efficiently using [xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/ERA5-GRIB-example.html) with the [cfgrib](https://pypi.org/project/cfgrib/) engine.

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("era5-2mt-2019-03-uk.grib", engine="cfgrib")
```

It reads all messages much more quickly than iterating them with pygrib.